# Got this error using repeat function: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please, can someone help out. I got this error when using repeat command.

```js
function repeat(s, n, d) {
    return --n ? s + (d || "") + repeat(s, n, d) : "" + s;
}
```

Comment: What does the **call** to that function look like? (What is the value of `n` in particular)?

Comment: for me this function works. What is the Error for what call?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, add some more information to make your problem more "clear"

Comment: I'd recall IE8 and earlier chocked when passed the same argument name recursively. I hope that you're not on IE8, though. Please answer questions in above comments, and also explain the [arrays] tag.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown in the case of a large value of parameter "n" (ie. 30000). In this case, **you have to avoid the recursion**.

Comment: This is actually browser dependent. FF42 chokes on 6001.